# How to alter CP entry edit form

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, users, permissions

On an entry edit form I'd like to alter the options in a multiselect field to be user relative. Is there something like a form_alter hook?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the native multiselect field, try using one of these plugins...

- [LJ Dynamic Fields](https://plugins.craftcms.com/craft-dynamic-fields)
- [Super Dynamic Fields](https://plugins.craftcms.com/super-dynamic-fields)

Either of them should allow you to create a dynamic multiselect field.